# Why do compute shader threads fail randomly on mobile, but not on PC?

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, mobile, shader, compute-shader

When I run my soft body physics sim on PC, it works fine. On the Oculus Quest's mobile GPU unfortunately, threads (semi) randomly fail to run for all of the various compute shader kernels. It becomes clear when I color code the mesh vertices according to which kernel last touched them: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/552308534906454017/663545642479648778/Gif_509.gif

On the PC in Unity editor, the model is solid blue, but on mobile it's a flickery mess. The failure patterns seem to change when I change the shader dispatches around; Some sets of dispatches have minimal thread failures https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/552308534906454017/663555876736729140/Gif_510.gif

The problems started when I moved beyond 3 dispatches per frame- Then got better at 6, then worse at 20, then better-ish again at 12 dispatches (rough numbers fyi). Number of workgroups per dispatch seems to have some effect too..? Renderdoc shows lots of leeway on the mobile GPU, so it's not due to overload- But changing the load seems to have some effect, sometimes...

I've been on this for about a week (spread over 6 months) and I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: Probably something went wrong with drivers or something that is responsible for rendering. I also had problems with my shaders on mobile, the problem was that some phones do not support some shader functionality like moving position of vertecies.

Comment: There is not enough information to give an answer... graphics target APIs, some code...really, it could be everything. HLSL in Unity gets translated to various APIs, but they all have their quirks and limitations.

Comment: @kefren Well compute shaders don't use graphics targets to my knowledge... The vertex/fragment/surface shaders etc work fine (running "#pragma target 5.0"). The compute shader is 1400 lines and has a dozen kernels, all of which miss threads in a somewhat random pattern. I have no idea what code to share.

  EDIT:
The oculus quest runs a snapdragon 835 GPU which uses tiling (desktops use instant rendering). I'll test it on my phone later but that runs the same GPU, so... idk

Comment: Compute shaders use the same APIs as vertex shaders. When you code a compute shader in Unity, in HLSL, it gets translated to the API you are targeting, if it's not DirectX. The translation means that you need to comply with (often not completely evident) limitations of that API. The editor often uses DirectX. The different behaviour might be due to this, so knowing your target API becomes fundamental.

Comment: @kefren looking at the running shader code in renderdoc, the CS kernels are running "#version 310 es". Here's a simpler kernel as a TXT https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/371347717030412298/664646564026777640/message.txt . This lines up with Unity's docs. Hmm what could be different in OpenGL ES 3.1 vs DX11 to make every kernel miss threads...

Comment: @kefren Update: Tested on android phones and it seems to only glitch on the Note 8, which has the same processor as the Quest. The Note 9 has no thread failures! (More testing coming). This makes me think it's a driver specific error. (I have no idea how to deal with that, contact samsung..?)